# Is it possible to have inheritance in rule based styling on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style

Currently using QGIS to draw some waste water network.

Styling depends on the size of pipe (thickness of the line)

[image]

AND on the status of the pipe (continuous, doted, ...)

[image]

It's actually fine since I had three size classes, but when changing to 10 size classes, it becomes to heavy to maintain since each class must be defined by hand.

This would be useful on many projects.

Comment: What do you need exactly?  As what would you like to have as a feature here.

Comment: Could you post a image of your rules that you currently using.

Comment: @NathanW The idea would be to set styling sub rules. Example : 
General rule : line thickness is a parameter of pipe size (like we do actually with graduated classification)
Sub rule : line style is a parameter of pipe status (like we would do actually with categorised)

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to define styling fields attached to the data set using the field calculator.

EX:

```
Field "thickness" -> classified pipe size value
```

[image: Field Calculator]

```
FIeld "style" -> Classified pipe status value
```

And then use these values to draw with specific parameters.

[image]

But this is not very intuitive and it will not print correctly the legend.

OR Use the right way and use rule enhancement option (Not stable actually on QGIS 2.16) but where you can add a sub rule to mainly change color

1. Add a primary Styling on size

[image: Size Filtering]

2. Go to Rules [image: Rules]
3. Add rule enhancement
   [image: Add sub rules]

Mainly color and size, not shape